# How to categories wpf combobox items (bound with observable collection ) & each category must display different background colors

Tags: wpf

I am new in WPF and I have wpf application with MVVM pattern + Prism, i have a combo-box bound with observable collection type.

Account Has : **Id** (PK), **AccountName**

I have built some account (built In for user) having Ids from 8000 to 10000, rest are generating, via app, > 10000, by mistake some Ids < 8000 has been created (not editable as running application)

Now i need to categories items in combo box based on Id group (8000 to 10000) and (Ids > 10000) and (1 to < 8000) and also wants these categories show different backgrounds in combo box.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean you are going to have more than 10000 records in ComboBox or do you mean three categories in Combobox 1) <8000, 2) 8000 to 10000 3) above 10000

Comment: Actually 1) <8000 has only 10 recs.  2)8000 to 10000 has only 100 recs.  3) above 10000 may have many recs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks 'Jan Smuda' for quick answering, yes this solved my problem, but i used another way to do this!
I have used ObservableCollection

> Account

, named as '_EntityCollection' for binding with Combobox and i have used Converter for grouping accounts :

```
 public class AccountIdConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var v = value as int?;

        if (v == null)
            return value;

        return Convert(v.Value);
    }

    public static string Convert(int id)
    {
        if (id >= 1 && id <= 8000)
            return "1-8000";
        else if (id >= 8001 && id <= 10000)
            return "8001-10000";


            return "> 10001";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <coverter:AccountIdConverter x:Key="AccIdConverter" />

    <!--Create CollectionViewSource and set the property we want to group by-->
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyItems" Source="{Binding _EntityCollection}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Id"  Converter="{StaticResource AccIdConverter}"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>





  <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyItems},Mode=OneWay}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="AccountName" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedItemIndex,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="250" Margin="10,5,0,5">

        <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
            <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" BorderBrush="#FF002255" BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <DockPanel>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                        <Expander.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="Expander">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupItem}, Path=DataContext.Name}" Value="1-8000">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF002255" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEEEEEE" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>

                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupItem}, Path=DataContext.Name}" Value="8001-10000">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Maroon" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>

                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupItem}, Path=DataContext.Name}" Value="> 10001">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>

                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Expander.Style>

                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>             

        </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox>
```

Yes, this solved my problem Nicely! all items are in different categories, under Expander with different background colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to group items in your combo box and data template selector to change background color in groups.

Grouping in combobox: see [tutorial](http://www.jarloo.com/wpf-combobox-with-groupings/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585017/grouping-items-in-a-combobox)

Data template selector: see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)

Example:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ComboboxGroups.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:ComboboxGroups">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="tmpl1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Green" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="tmpl2">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="tmpl3">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Yellow"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Local:TemplateSelector x:Key="tmplselector"
        Tmpl1="{StaticResource tmpl1}" Tmpl2="{StaticResource tmpl2}" Tmpl3="{StaticResource tmpl3}" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}" DisplayMemberPath="Account.AccountName">
        <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HeaderTemplateSelector="{StaticResource tmplselector}" />                    
        </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

View model and entity types:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
}

public class ComboboxGroup<TItem>
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }        
    public TItem Account { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ListCollectionView Accounts
    {
        get { return _Accounts; }
        set
        {
            if (_Accounts != value)
            {
                _Accounts = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Accounts);
            }
        }
    }
    private ListCollectionView _Accounts;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var accounts = new List<Account>();
        accounts.Add(new Account() { Id = 1, AccountName = "Acount 1"});
        accounts.Add(new Account() { Id = 2, AccountName = "Acount 2" });
        accounts.Add(new Account() { Id = 9000, AccountName = "Acount 9000" });
        accounts.Add(new Account() { Id = 9001, AccountName = "Acount 9001" });
        accounts.Add(new Account() { Id = 10000, AccountName = "Acount 10000" });
        accounts.Add(new Account() { Id = 10001, AccountName = "Acount 10002" });

        var groups = new List<ComboboxGroup<Account>>();

        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            if (account.Id >= 1 && account.Id < 8000)                
                groups.Add(new ComboboxGroup<Account>() { Account = account, CategoryName = "<1;8000)"});                
            else if (account.Id >= 8000 && account.Id <= 10000)                
                groups.Add(new ComboboxGroup<Account>() { Account = account, CategoryName = "<8000;10000>" });                
            else                
                groups.Add(new ComboboxGroup<Account>() { Account = account, CategoryName = "(10000; infinity)" });                
        }

        Accounts = new ListCollectionView(groups);
        Accounts.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("CategoryName"));
    }        
}
```

DataTemplate selector:

```
public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Tmpl1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Tmpl2 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Tmpl3 { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        CollectionViewGroup group = (CollectionViewGroup)item;
        if (group.Name.ToString() == "<1;8000)")            
            return Tmpl1;
        else if (group.Name.ToString() == "<8000;10000>")            
            return Tmpl2;
        else if (group.Name.ToString() == "(10000; infinity)")            
            return Tmpl3;            

        return null;
    }
}
```