# WPF how to combine two comboboxes with different itemsource into one

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, itemsource

Lets say that I currently have two Comboboxes, one that displays the contents of the **Productions** list and one that displays the contents of the **Seasons** list from the viewmodel.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Productions}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduction}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" />
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Seasons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduction}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" />
```

What I need to do is combine these two Comboboxes into one. When clicking on the Combobox it should show a header saying Productions and below each production should appear and bellow all that it should do the same with the Seasons. So graphically it should look something like this:

[Combobox Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5uTD.png)

**Productions**

production1

production2

production3

**Seasons**

season1

season2

season3

1. I suppose that in order to use both lists as an ItemSource I could
   make a list which contains both Production and Season lists, but is
   there another way to bind them both in the same combobox?
2. And then is it even possible to make it look like in the picture?

Comment: See the solution explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585017/grouping-items-in-a-combobox
And group with typeof(). You will also need a common interface to join the 2 lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [CompositeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) which was designed specifically for such usage.

For the grouping, the link @Floc mentioned in a comment shows how to use to use [Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585017/grouping-items-in-a-combobox).

With these two, I think you can achieve success. As long as both classes derive from something common to expose similar properties, this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you both, this was exactly what I wanted to do :)