# WPF Group Items in ComboBox programmatically (Creating Data Templates in Code)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I need to group my Items in a Combobox like this.

> [Category]
>   - Item
>   - Item
>   [Category2]
>   - Item
>   - Item

I found an working answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585017/grouping-items-in-a-combobox), but my comboboxes are created dynamically by User Action.
Is it possible to fill the Combobox like this programmatically?

The Items I want to display are ModuleCategoryViewControl's :

```
public class ClassNameController
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.Type ObjectType { get; set; }
    public ClassNameController(string name, Type objectType)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ObjectType = objectType;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
class ModuleCategoryViewControl : ClassNameController
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public ModuleCategoryViewControl(string name, string category, Type objectType) : base(name, objectType)
    {
        this.Category = category;
    }
}
```

They should group by `Category` and displayed by `Name`

Comment: Sorry, I linked the wrong question. Fixed it now.

Comment: i thinks its duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585017/grouping-items-in-a-combobox

Comment: @RaviKanth it isn't. The Question you posted is the one I linked but its not solving the problem programmatically :)

Comment: I'd love to hear the reasons for the downvotes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to fill the Combobox like this programmatically?

The sample code on the link you supplied does fill the `ComboBox` programmatically so it's unclear what your issue really is.

If you add items dynamically at runtime you should replace the `List<ModuleCategoryViewControl>` with an `ObservableCollection<ModuleCategoryViewControl>`.

Please refer to the following sample code.

**Window.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    readonly ObservableCollection<ModuleCategoryViewControl> items = new ObservableCollection<ModuleCategoryViewControl>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        items.Add(new ModuleCategoryViewControl("Item2", "A", typeof(int)));
        items.Add(new ModuleCategoryViewControl("Item2", "A", typeof(int)));
        items.Add(new ModuleCategoryViewControl("Item3", "A", typeof(int)));
        items.Add(new ModuleCategoryViewControl("Item4", "B", typeof(int)));
        items.Add(new ModuleCategoryViewControl("Item5", "B", typeof(int)));


        ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(items);
        lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));

        comboBox.ItemsSource = lcv;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        items.Add(new ModuleCategoryViewControl("Item6", "A", typeof(int)));
        items.Add(new ModuleCategoryViewControl("Item7", "C", typeof(int)));
    }
}
```

**Window.xaml:**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="sp">
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox">
        <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

    <Button Content="Add Item" Click="Button_Click" />

</StackPanel>
```

If you want to create the DataTemplates programmatically you could use the `XamlReader.Parse` method:

```
ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
cmb.GroupStyle.Add(System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse("<GroupStyle xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate><DataTemplate><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding Name}\"/></DataTemplate></GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate></GroupStyle>") as GroupStyle);
cmb.ItemTemplate = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding Name}\"/></DataTemplate>") as DataTemplate;
cmb.ItemsSource = lcv;

sp.Children.Add(cmb);
```

Comment: Apparently, I expressed myself unclear. I wanted to create the DataTemplates programmtically :) Your answer worked like a charm.