# UWP grouping items in ComboBox

Tags: xaml, uwp

I search to group items in a ComboBox control like this:

group

- item 1
- item 2

group 2

- item3

...

So, I tried this example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585017/grouping-items-in-a-combobox) which is for WPF but does not work for UWP because ListCollectionView does not exist. So I tried with CollectionViewSource without any success.

Thanks

Samuel

Comment: Define "So I tried with CollectionViewSource without any success".

Comment: I can not use it to do what I want because its operation is not similar to that of ListCollectionView

Comment: I'm afraid you may need to custom the control  yourself.

Comment: This is a serious regression compared to WPF