# How to add subitem in dropbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got unfinished project and my first steps is to modify main menu which is based on combobox and looks like in GitHub desktop application

[image: Default view]

So now task is to group similar items into subgroups.

For example *Log View*, *Cities View* and *Stores View* should be placed under the group *Administration*. And years 2017...2020 should be placed under one group.

Unfortunately I can't find solution for this task, maybe ComboBox is not the best solution for this. Maybe someone can give me direction where my solution is? It can either collapsible group or like menu-style, when nested items appears on right of the group.

P.S **Administration** and **Year Table Administration** is just empty combobox items.

Comment: You could set or bind the `ItemsSource` property to a grouped `CollectionView`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585017/grouping-items-in-a-combobox

Comment: Thanks, but in this solution I can't collapse groups.

Comment: @SBarbovskis: Add an expander to the `GroupStyle` if you want this.

Answer (score 0):

So, my solution is based on thies https://stackoverflow.com/a/3585244/7283900

I added Expander to my ComboBox, so entire solution now looks like

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1_TEST.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1_TEST"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="GroupItem" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander x:Name="expander" 
                                      ExpandDirection="Down">

                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2,5,0,2" FontSize="14"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <Expander.Content>
                                    <Border Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                        <ItemsPresenter >
                                        </ItemsPresenter>
                                    </Border>
                                </Expander.Content>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ComboBox Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Item}"
                  Margin="162,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="195" Name="cboGroup" >
            <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupItem}"/>
            </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

And CodeBehind of this page

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item1", Category = "Category_1" });
        items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item2", Category = "Category_1" });
        items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item3", Category = "Category_1" });
        items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item4", Category = "Category_2" });
        items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item5", Category = "Category_2" });

        ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(items);
        lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));

        //this.comboBox.ItemsSource = lcv;
        this.cboGroup.ItemsSource = lcv;
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }


}
```