# Grouping items in ComboBox in XAML only

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, grouping

I'm aware that I can group items in a `ComboBox` by [creating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585017/grouping-items-in-a-combobox) a `ListCollectionView` in code and setting a `GroupDescription`.

I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid using code behind, by populating the `ListCollectionView` directly in `XAML`.

In my case, the `ComboBox` has a fixed list of elements with `DynamicBindings` in them. So it would be easier for me to stay in `XAML`.

Here's the simplified example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="ExportItemArray" Type="{x:Type i:ExportItem}">
        <i:ExportItem Name="Audio" Description="WAV"/>
        <i:ExportItem Name="Image" Description="PNG Image"/>
        <i:ExportItem Name="Video" Description="Mp4 Video"/>
    </x:Array>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionViewSource" Source="{Binding ExportItemArray}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource CollectionViewSource}">
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

The `CollectionViewSource` is not being accepted by the `ComboBox`, since it's a proxy type of `CollectionView` instead of `ListCollectionView`.

I'm not sure if there's any proxy for `ListCollectionView`.

Comment: When I use collection view source for items source, I usually do `{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSource}}`

Comment: I understand now, thanks to you, that my `Binding` would never work. I'm a bit rusty in XAML. The `ComboBox` is not accepting the `CollectionViewSource` as its `ItemSource`.

Comment: My issue was that I was using Binding inside the `Source` of the `CollectionViewSource` too.

Comment: Yes, `Source="{Binding ExportItemArray}"` is also invalid. You needed `Source="{StaticResource ExportItemArray}"` there instead. But you can't use the `StaticResource` syntax for setting `ItemsSource` to a `CollectionViewSource`, and that's all you were really explicitly asking in the question, hence the duplicate.