# WPF - Create ComBox with multiple separators

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, separator

I want to make a `ComboBox` with ***0-N*** `Separators`

I was able to do this with `CompositeCollection` like so

```
<ComboBox.ItemsSource>
  <CompositeCollection>
     <CollectionContainer Collection ={Binding mysrc1}/>
     <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled = "False">
        <Separator Background = "White" Height=10/>
     </ComboBoxItem>
     <CollectionContainer Collection ={Binding mysrc2}/>
       <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled = "False">
          <Separator Background = "White" Height=10/>
     </ComboBoxItem>
  </CompositeCollection>
 </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

But this is kind of clunky and with a lot of code duplication but in `.View` and in `.ViewModel`

I was thinking about using custom control that will Inherit from `ComboBox` and use `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached` for the location of the `Separator`(s)

but couldn't find a way to do so

P.S

i prefer not use any code behind and not use `<Setter Property="Template">` because i have base style and template that a lot of `ComboBox`s in my program user

Comment: Have you considered binding itemssource to List<object> and data templating viewmodels into separators? That's how I do separators usually.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using databinding, the items are grouped, so I would using grouping.

See this answer: [Grouping items in a ComboBox (solved)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3585244/20979917)

If you do not want to use grouping, then you could use this method: [Insert ComboBox Item Separator Which is Filled Through Data Binding](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17936.insert-combobox-item-separator-which-is-filled-through-data-binding.aspx)

Comment: how would grouping would help me? i have seen the 2nd solution. TBH it looks bad and it dosent help my problem